# RDBMS code 6706: The string contains an untranslatable character in teradata

Tags: teradata

I got the following error while inserting data into teradata DB using data stage job, I can not see data file and all the fields in **#table** are **varchar**, below is my code:

```
insert into #table
(
 column1,
 column2
)
values
(
column1_value,
column2_value
);
```

Error:

```
RDBMS code 6706: The string contains an untranslatable character
```

Comment: Either you have some unicode hanging out in your code and have connected to Teradata without specifying a unicode character set, or you have unicode hanging out in your data, and your column definition is set up as LATIN in your create table DDL. You may need to convert your data to ASCII/LATIN using the TRANSLATE() function like `TRANSLATE(column1_value USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE)` or similar. Or Drop/Recreate your table and set the column up as `CHARACTER SET UNICODE`.

Comment: For this, first I have to know the exact column name to be converted to unicode, right??

Comment: Find out how the target table is defined, and in datastage, convert your data to the appropriate character set.

Comment: Thanku, Is there a way that I can load all the data without converting my data according to data types of my target table?

Comment: To be of help, information about the char-set of source, target and the client used is needed. An example of data, which causes the error, would be helpful too. Which client are you using? `values(...)` usually needs fixed strings or some type of placeholders. What do you expect the database to do, if a character can't be converted? Just forget it or use something similiar or guess, what you might like?

Comment: Thanks @Ulick , i recreated the target table with "CHARACTER SET  UNICODE" and in my datastage teradata connector properties the client character set is utf8